# Getting query result back as array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am having the following query:

```
            SELECT *
            FROM instruments
            LEFT join financials on instruments.id=financials.instruments_id
            WHERE financials.id IN
            ( SELECT MAX(financials.id)
            FROM financials
            GROUP BY financials.instruments_id )
            ORDER BY instruments.id ASC
```

Below is my eloquent translation:

```
$overviewArray = DB::table('instruments')
    ->leftJoin('financials', 'instruments.id', '=', 'financials.instruments_id')
    ->whereIn('financials.id', DB::raw('SELECT MAX(financials.id)
    FROM financials
    GROUP BY financials.instruments_id )
    ORDER BY instruments.id ASC'))->toArray();
```

I would like to get the result as array back so i used `toArray()`:

However, I am getting the following error:

```
In Builder.php line 2461:

  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::toArray()
```

Any suggestions why this is the case?

I appreciate your replies!

**UPDATE:**

After adding `->get()` to the end of my query, I get the following error:

In Grammar.php line 135:

```
  Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, object given, called
  in C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Coding Projects\demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Gramm
  ars\Grammar.php on line 250
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `get()` to the query to execute it:

```
DB::table('instruments')->(....)->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: Thx for your reply! However, I am now getting the following error: `Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, object given, called
  in C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Coding Projects\demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Gramm
  ars\Grammar.php on line 250`

Answer (score 2):

After getting query builder result,

```
$result = DB::table('instruments as i')
    ->leftJoin('financials as f', 'i.id', '=', 'f.instruments_id')
    ->whereIn('f.id', DB::raw('SELECT MAX(f.id) FROM financials as fs GROUP BY fs.instruments_id'))
    ->orderBy('i.id')
    ->get();
```

Either use, `(array) $result`

```
$overviewArray = (array) $result;
```

Or `json_decode(json_encode(...))` to convert in array

```
$overviewArray = json_decode(json_encode($result), true);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Please have a look at my updated question.

Comment: @mrquad : did you try what I said `, just use `->get()` and one of above given solution to change in Array ?

Comment: Jup I did. I think there is something wrong with my query translation.

Comment: @mrquad : can you share which method works for you ?

Comment: Basically, I get an error at the `->get()` method. The conversion of the array should be then no problem yet. Do you see any error with my posted query?

Comment: I think `ORDER BY i.id ASC` is wrongly placed here and in your query there was extra `)`

Comment: Thx for your reply! How would the correct query look like?

Comment: Changed query in answer

Comment: Thx for your reply! I still get this error `Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Coding Projects\demo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Databa‌​se\Query\Gramm ars\Grammar.php on line 250`.

Comment: I doubt in `->whereIn('f.id'` plz try with direct value  ` like `->where('f.id',2)`

Answer (score 1):

`toArray()` shows exception when no record found based on the query(Single record).
For this just handle exception before using `toArray()`

Example:

```
$data = DB::table('instruments')->(....)->first();
if($data!=null){
 $arrayData = $data->toArray();
}
```